# Observer Pattern Across websites

Tags: oop, design-patterns

Recently I've been reading alot regarding design patterns, and I've seen at least one that, in theory I can use on my job.

We have a couple of websites that just parse XML feeds from other websites inside the website network and display them to the users. The current implementation is, in my opinion rather dull, since when one VM with a website flips out, the sites that get the feeds are either halted or slow to a crawl.

Upon reading about the observer pattern, I thought that this would be a great idea to implement but I have some questions:

1- how would I go about implementing this "logic" across websites?

2- Would each site that provides the feeds be an observer and the sites that read the feed observables?

3- related to 2: Would it be wise to have a "central" observer that gathers the feeds of all of the websites and the sites that need it would just plug into that observer?

Thanks for the help

Comment: you can use a message broker to implement the something very similar to the observer pattern between separate applications, web, or otherwise.  The applications can either be on the same server, or different ones.  ActiveMQ is one such service.

Answer (score 0):

1- how would I go about implementing this "logic" across websites?

->Yes, generally this design pattern is able to applied anywhere that have one object notifies state changes to many other objects with decoupling relationships between observables and observers. Those notifications can be transferred over network or transferred inside one host.

->But for your question, in my view, implementation of this pattern is not practical because server that provides feeds often plays passive role which give feeds via some url, and active role often played by sites that want to read feeds from it. In observer pattern, observable always is active, and observers are always passive.

2- Would each site that provides the feeds be an observer and the sites that read the feed observables?

-> According to answer to question 1, because it is not practical in my view, so do not need to discuss more.

3- related to 2: Would it be wise to have a "central" observer that gathers the feeds of all of the websites and the sites that need it would just plug into that observer?

-> No, it is not observer pattern. By definition " Defines a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically ". Your thought said about "many to one dependencies".